# SQL select column and count from the next column

Tags: count, mariadb

My table structure for referrals is , the field ref is unique:

```
ID  pid  ref   ref_by  
1    1   k      NAN
2    2   l      k
3    3   m      k
4    4   n      l
```

And the user table is:

```
id    name   
1     john  
2     Bob  
3     Tim   
4     Rob
```

I need to get the id,pid, ref and count of ref in next column .Based on the number of referrals they each will be assigned some points that is a constant 100, the result should look like this .

```
pid  name   ref   number_of_referals  points_earned 
1     john   k      2                   200
2     Bob    l      1                   100
3     Tim    m      0                     0
4     Rob    n      0                     0
```

Comment: Please don't tag multiple RDBMS. Please only tag the one you are actually using; tagging multiple makes it harder for the users here to answer, not get more users to answer it. I've removed the 2 tags, please edit your post and tag only the RDBMS you are using. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need 2 joins: 
the 1st from `users` table to `referrals` and  the 2nd to a query that groups and counts the referrals:

```
select 
  r.id, u.name, r.ref,
  case when c.counter is null then 0 else c.counter end number_of_referals,
  case when c.counter is null then 0 else c.counter end * 100 points_earned
from users u inner join referrals r
on r.pid = u.id
left join (select ref_by, count(*) counter from referrals group by ref_by) c
on c.ref_by = r.ref
order by r.id
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pfriivVMaYyPcVom89xHuj/0)